# I use spring security and axios to get data , but it seems that the get request can't pass the security check

Tags: spring, spring-security, axios

This is my axios, I use get method and add username&password into request. But I don't know why this can not pass backend check. By the way I'm pretty sure about the url is correct.

```
axios({
                    method:'get',
                    url,
                    auth: {
                        username: 'From_Website',
                        password: 'aycfgz!'
                    }
                }).then((response) =>{
                    console.log(response.data);
                    this.myblogs = response.data;
                    this.len = this.myblogs.length;
                }).catch(err =>{
                    console.log(err);
                });
```

And this is my backend configration code.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled=true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder) throws Exception{
        authenticationManagerBuilder.inMemoryAuthentication()
                .passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder())
                .withUser("From_Website")
                .password(new BCryptPasswordEncoder().encode("aycfgz!"))
                .roles("from_website");

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

What error are you getting and where? From the top of my head, you can try adding `withCredentials: true` config to your request.